# Handle POST array object from JSON, avoid error ECONNREFUSED Socket hang up

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, sockets, loopback

I have data.json file type array object with array length ~ 4000, each object has ~ 200 property.
When I read file and POST to loopback api and I got error ECONNREFUSED Socket hang up.

How to handle when POST a large JSON ?

```
const runPOST = async () => {
    let rawJson = fs.readFileSync('./data.json', 'utf-8');
    let res = JSON.parse(rawJson)

    const baseUrl = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < res.length; i += 100) {
        const requests = res.slice(i, i + 100);
        requests.map(v => axios.post(baseUrl, v));

        await Promise.all(requests).catch(r => console.log(r));
    }
}
runPOST();
```

I used loopback3.x in localhost with db type memory

```
// datasources.json
"db": {
    "name": "db",
    "connector": "memory",
    "file": "db.json"
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue has nothing to do with the size of your payload.

Here is an **explanation of "Connection refused" error**:

At the stage of establishing of TCP connection (in your case) client sends SYN packet to the server but receives response packet with flag RST.

It means that your connection can't be established because server side is not running any service at requested port.

This happens long before you start sending your data to the server so your issue is not related to the size of your data at all.

These RST packets can also be sent when firewall is configured to REJECT connections based on some criteria.

So in your case you need to check:

- content of baseUrl variable (ohh. wait. it is empty :-) )
- status of service itself (which you are trying to reach)
- firewall rules

Also you can sniff traffic to see what actually happens.